# Why Operator overloading and not Operator Overriding?

Tags: oop

> Overloading is defining multiple methods with same name but different number of parameters and different datatype of parameters

> Overriding is redefinition of base class function in its derived class with same signature i.e return type and parameters

For operators, some methods must have been defined in base classes and when we redefine those methods in our classes, we call them operator overloading. However, shouldn't it be called operator overriding? Also, we cannot change the parameters of the methods, so isn't operator overloading more similar to overriding? 
I am really confused in this very basic thing.

Comment: You might want to specify a language, so that answers can mention things specific to that language and be more useful. I'm sure many languages handle operator overloading differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not overriding, because you are not changing the functionalities of existing operators. For example, you can't change what `1 + 1` does with operator overloading.

What operator overloading allows you to do is to define new operators. For example, you can define a `+` that operates on two int arrays (assuming your language doesn't already support this). If you think of the `+` operator as a function, the existing `+` operators might have signatures:

```
double +(double, double)
int +(int, int)
string +(string, string)
```

Now you are adding a new operator:

```
int[] +(int[], int[])
```

These "functions" all have the same name `+` but different parameters. This is similar to the situation in overloading, so the language feature is called operator overloading.